# Integrate Google analytics with website API

Tags: wordpress, api, google-analytics

I am looking just looking for tools that are required to achieve the following

My aim to give my website users analytics reports for the pages created by them(user). I am having a WordPress website

- Data Source ( Analytics )
- How to connect? ( Which API ?)
- How to store the analytics value to PHP variable? ( a simple example if possible )
- How does the graph are plotted? Is it possible to get the google plot and display in user dashbord
- even if i am able to connect i will be getting entire website data how can i set it up for a user specific page

Please note that i am not asking for complete solution just the tools required.
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect it to the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) and use something like [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) to visualise your charts.

You are likely to have issues authenticating so look at this [page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization) regarding the ways you may authenticate.

Finally, once you've sorted out the authentication - the following [page](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) is mighty helpful to generate your requests.